# How do I get the parameter to be read properly in rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am running into and issue with how a parameter is getting detected in production for my rails app.

My controller:

```
def search
    puts "param is #{params[:dp]}"
    if params[:dp]
      redirect_to controller: 'products', action: 'results', product: params[:dp]
    end
end
```

In production, if I type in "http://example.com/?dp=123", the controller doesn't read param[:dp]; meaning, nothing is printed to the console. However, if I am on example.com and then add the parameter after loading this page, then

```
 puts "param is #{params[:dp]}"
```

works fine.

Even stranger, on my localhost environment, the parameter is detected regardless of which method I take.

My question: how do I get the parameter to be read properly when I navigate directly to a site with the 'dp' parameter?

Answer (score 0):

what you need is this:

```
redirect_to controller: 'products', action: 'results', params: {product: params[:dp]}
```

Another way is to use flash:

```
flash[:product]= params[:dp]
```

or Session cookies, but remember to not put too much data on params or flash or session cookies, since they're limited to a certain size.